# Moving around display connections in many monitor, multiple workstation setup (hdmi switch?)

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, hotswapping

I have a 6 screen setup with 3 workstations, and generally my layout works ok.  However, depending on what task I'm currently working on, different screen layouts would be more optimal.  For example, I generally have 4 monitors connected to my development machine, and 1 to each of the other workstations (call them A and B), but there are times when I'm working mainly on one of the other machines where I'd like to swap out and have 3 monitors allocated to workstation A.

I currently have hacked this by using 6 hdmi extenders that connect to the monitors and hang down near my keyboard, and a bunch of hdmi cables coming up from the workstations.  This works, however its very ugly.

I googled hdmi switch, but those generally seem to be many inputs to one output - not really organizing multiple output connections.  My question is - is there any sort of hardware that would do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple HDMI switches, one for each monitor that may need input from more than one computer. So for your example, two of the monitors will need to get their output from corresponding HDMI switches, and those HDMI switches will need both "development" and "A" as their inputs. This will allow you to switch "A" from having one monitor to three monitors, stealing monitors from "development".

Using VNC or X11 forwarding is likely to be a more convenient and cheaper solution. Or virtualization, if the only reason you have multiple machines is to run multiple OSes.

Answer (score 0):

How about getting a monitor that accepts 2 different input (most monitors accepts at least DVI and VGA), and select the input from the monitor?

In example:
Dev PC --> M1, M2, M3, M4
PC A --> M5 (HDMI), M1 (DVI)
PC B --> M6 (HDMI), M2 (DVI)

So when you work on A, you can do "select input" on the monitor, to show display from the DVI port so then you will have M5 and M1 dual-display for A (and same method for B).

And also as wingedsubmariner answer goes, you can also use VNC, or Remote Desktop or TeamViewer depends on what OS are running on all different 3 PCs.